# Can I get Apple Mail’s junk filter to identify junk mail better?

Tags: mail.app

In my experience Gmail’s junk filter is super-accurate but Apple’s is not. I get emails from senders which I mark as junk but which continue. Is it know that Apple mail’s junk filter is less good? Is it known why? And, is there any way to improve it?

Comment: No one can really be better than Gmail these days.  The effectiveness of modern spam filtering (such as Naive Bayesian https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_spam_filtering -- though I'm sure Google uses a much more advanced model than this) is a function of how much training data it receives (the sheer volume of labelled spam vs ham emails a filter sees).  With Gmail being the largest email provider, no one can beat Google at collecting training data for spam filtering.  even if you labeled every email you ever receive as spam vs ham, you'd still not beat Google at this.

Answer (score 1):

The built in Spam filtering engine cannot be “taught” by the user to improve its filtering.  You can create rules that will help keep your inbox less cluttered, but to really get intelligent Spam filtering, you need a 3rd party product

- [SpamSieve](https://c-command.com/spamsieve/) Is a local client that works with Apple Mail and has decent reviews.  I’ve used similar products in the past with good results.
- [Hosted Exchange](https://products.office.com/en-us/exchange/compare-microsoft-exchange-online-plans) with integrated Spam filtering is a cloud based solution (I personally go this route).  Managing an email server and configuring Spam heuristics is just too time consuming, so I let someone else handle it and I’ve been quite pleased with the results.

Comment: "cannot be taught" is a perhaps too strong an assertion.  https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/reduce-junk-mail-mlhlp1065/mac help documention claims that "Each time you confirm a message as junk or not junk, the junk mail filter improves so Mail can better identify junk mail."

Comment: @vykor they do in fact “claim” that.